# SQL SSRS Spatial Location remove outliers. Or select top 100 only

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, spatial

I am creating a report that uses a Map. I have database of every city, their longitude, and latitude, and I use that to create a Spatial Location which I map onto a SSRS map.

99% of the data points seem right, but there are a few that appear to be in the ocean. Is there any way to get rid of these points? They cause my map to become small.

[image]

Maybe the best way is to just select the top 100 spatial points, instead of all.
Is that possible?

[image]

Can I change this expression to have it so it does top 100 spatial points by another field (customer value) or since my query is already sorted, should I just select the top 100? Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Getting the sense that the outliers are Alaska, Hawaii, and PR or US VI.

Comment: Yep, seems to be actually. Do you know if there is a way to do the expresion so it only selects top 100 rows for the spatial location field?

Comment: Perhaps where Lng > -120  to exclude AK and HI and  Lat> 20 to exclude PR

Comment: Great idea! That worked. Will using those coordinates only exclude those territories? Do you know if it cuts in Florida or Californa?

Comment: They will exclude anything WEST of CA and SOUTH of FL